# CMD/Bash/Batch Script to get item/filters

Tags: bash, batch-file, cmd

For example, I have items.txt

In items.txt

There's multiple lines

```
test1=import1
test1=import2
test2=import1
test1=import3
test2=import4
test3=import2
test3=import2
test1=import1
test1=import2
test2=import1
test1=import3
test2=import4
test3=import2
test3=import2
test1=import1
test1=import2
test2=import1
test1=import3
test2=import4
test3=import2
test3=import2
test1=import1
test1=import2
test2=import1
test1=import3
test2=import4
test3=import2
test3=import2
test1=import1
test1=import2
test2=import1
test1=import3
test2=import4
test3=import2
test3=import2
```

What I need to do is to get atleast 1 value from test1,test2,test3 or per item and so on. And pass it to another text file --> items2.txt

And in items2.txt

It should be like this

```
test1 
test2
test3
```

and their values.

Comment: Are you using `bash` or `cmd`? Those are two (very) different shells.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to program this for you? This is the wrong site - there are plenty of other coder for hire sites.

Comment: I'm not here to ask someone to program this for me. I already have this code FORFILES /p C:\test\ /D -2 /S /C "cmd /c echo isdir path "|findstr "test1">items2.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ForFiles` does files not lines of text.

Use `For`, which does files, lines of text, and output of commands, and a few other things.

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %A in (c:\somefile.txt) do echo %A
```

Takes text before first = sign in a line of text in a file.

Redirection write screen output to a file. So this writes it to a file.

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %A in (c:\somefile.txt) do echo %A >>Output.txt
```

Here's a quick reference to characters in cmd.

```
&    seperates commands on a line.

&&    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

||    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

>    output to a file

>>    append output to a file

<    input from a file

|    output of one command into the input of another command

^    escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program

"    parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes

+ used with copy to concatinate files. E.G. copy file1+file2 newfile

, used with copy to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files modified date. E.G. copy /b file1,,

%variablename% a inbuilt or user set environmental variable

!variablename! a user set environmental variable expanded at execution time, turned with SelLocal EnableDelayedExpansion command

%<number> (%1) the nth command line parameter passed to a batch file. %0 is the batchfile's name.

%* (%*) the entire command line.

%<a letter> or %%<a letter> (%A or %%A) the variable in a for loop. Single % sign at command prompt and double % sign in a batch file.
```

Comment: Thank you for this one, its a great help.